# How to get workspace programmatically?

Tags: linux, eclipse, workspace

any one know how can I get current path of eclipse workspace programmatically. Since this path changes in every computer I want to get this thing programmatically and dynamically. It should return a string and it should be like `ersin/projects/proj/my_work_space_name`.

by the way this code didnt work for me:
`ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation().toString()`
it gives `ersin/projects/proj/runtime-EclipseApplication` whereas it should be `ersin/projects/proj/my_work_space_name`.

Comment: what is the purpose behind this?

Comment: I need this path because I will do some searching under workspace

Comment: do you mean an application absolute path?

Comment: I didnt get your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're getting that value because you're running a test environment for debugging a plugin.  When you do that, you're effectively running a different workspace and that's why you're getting the root location of that workspace.  Should you get to the point where you run that plugin in your original development workspace, you'll get the value you expect.

In short, you are getting the current path of the eclipse workspace.

So if you're trying to debug a plugin that searches the workspace, you'll need to add projects to your test workspace so that the search can take place there.

Comment: I have tried what u tell me, and I deployed my plugin into eclipse, it works fine in windows 7 but it doesnt work in Linux

Comment: @ersnbck What doesn't work on Linux? This answer describes exactly what is happening.

Comment: Use the debugger to find the line that doesn't work and then we can work out why